# I don't find mkcephfs tool

Tags: ceph

I am starting with Cepth and i am following the QuickStart Install Tutorial from the official [website](http://eu.ceph.com/docs/wip-6919/start/quick-start/) and in one step i need the tool MKCEPHFS but i don't find in the place where should be, /etc/ceph. Neither he is in /sbin/ folder. I am trying install and  test the Ceph system in one only host. I tried to do the installation from several forms but i don't find the problem.

Note:
`ceph version 0.87`

System: "Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"

These are the tools instaled:

`dpkg -l | grep ceph
ii  ceph                                   0.87-1trusty                  amd64        distributed storage and file system
ii  ceph-common                            0.87-1trusty                  amd64        common utilities to mount and interact with a ceph storage cluster
ii  ceph-deploy                            1.5.21trusty                  all          Ceph-deploy is an easy to use configuration tool
ii  ceph-fs-common                         0.87-1trusty                  amd64        common utilities to mount and interact with a ceph file system
ii  ceph-fuse                              0.87-1trusty                  amd64        FUSE-based client for the Ceph distributed file system
ii  ceph-mds                               0.87-1trusty                  amd64        metadata server for the ceph distributed file system
ii  libcephfs1                             0.87-1trusty                  amd64        Ceph distributed file system client library
ii  python-ceph                            0.87-1trusty                  amd64        Python libraries for the Ceph distributed filesystem`

Comment: How did you get to that documentation? It looks elderly, bearing in mind that [this issue with using the deprecated mkcephfs tool](http://tracker.ceph.com/issues/5926) (it's been replaced by ceph-deploy) was closed more than a year ago... I think it's probably been replaced by [this](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/).

Comment: You are right. In the latest version is not used MKCEPHFS. I saw elderly documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKCEPHFS tool has been replaced by ceph-deploy in the latest versions and in the [Storage Cluster Quick Start](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/) we can see how use it.

Answer (score 2):

As you use the version 0.87(Giant), you can see the doc here, http://ceph.com/docs/giant/start/.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same (apparently) ancient docs here 
http://eu.ceph.com/docs/wip-6919/start/quick-start/
in a seemingly authoritative place.